# Apps are hidden automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

I updated to iOS 15 and now when I install an app in the app store, it goes automagically to the App Library "hidden" there and to have it in my screen, I have to drag it.

How can I revert this behavior to what it used to be? (aka you install an app and the icon appears on the screen)

Comment: I'd encourage you to at least give this feature a try - it's a much more efficient way to manage apps when you have more than a few dozen.  Rather than finding what screen they're on and opening them, you drag down from _any_ screen, type a few letters, and the app opens.  Then, the only apps you need on your home screen(s) are the very commonly opened ones.

Comment: I gave it a try already, how do you think I asked this question in the first place? I think it’s a bad idea, if you download an app is most likely to use it and not hide it to use it next month. Think of a game, a noteapp, a mail app, etc, you download it, want to use it like a new toy for the next x days and then you optionally delete it or hide it. The point is that you want it visible to use it a lot at the begging. @Joe

Comment: @Joe , I'd say that differs among peoples. I personally can't think why Apple made this setting to default setting - It was like this since iPhoneOS 2.0 was released. If people want to hide what you downloaded, its choice must be up to user, not OS.

Comment: @Skye-AT Not saying it's best for *everyone*.  But, it is something I recommend trying for a few weeks - give yourself time to get used to it.  They made it default, for the same reason it's largely default on every other major computing platform: because screen after screen of single icons isn't an efficient way to find apps.  They're not "hiding" the app, it's in the App Library and accessible by search - which is by far the more efficient way to find apps, for most people.  Hopefully you find programs on your PC or Mac by using search, and not a desktop full of icons?

Comment: Most likely the explicit reason they made it default was that this was already well tested and used on Android - and the default there (see https://www.guidingtech.com/what-app-drawer-android/ for example).

Comment: @Joe I find my apps in my organized folder, not search, regardless of what device I'm using. But yeah, I can agree to your opinion; My answer would be no though... I use my Android as same as my iPhone :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable this feature(aka reverting it back), first navigate to Settings on your mobile. Then find and tap Home screen, and select the option Add to Home Screen.

So it'd work like as it used to be.